# О правильности употребления родительного падежа: "Я не буду целовать холодных рук..."

Tags: грамматика, родительный-или-винительный

Есть два предложения, сходные **по семантике**, но с разной **грамматикой**. В обоих случаях была использована **форма Р.п.**

(1) *Мне уже не видеть вас, не целовать **ваших рук.*** Это правильно?

(2) *Я не увижу вас, не буду целовать **ваших рук.*** Грамматическая ошибка?

Чем отличаются предложения? Почему разные решения?

**Примечание** (почему задан вопрос)

Ошибку нашли **в песне** на эту тему. И вот хотелось исправить текст наилучшим образом, не меняя **формы Р.п.,** которая нужна для рифмы.

Песня, кстати, довольно **известная**, душевная такая, но текст я немного **замаскировала**. Ошибка выглядит **незаметно,** но уж очень автор статьи возмущался ее наличием. Как можно это не видеть и т.д. Автор считает, что там должен быть В.п. (не буду целовать **ваши руки**). Вроде бы так, но почему эта погрешность не замечается. Что влияет: отрицание, партитивность? Как ее поправить?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150582/discussion-on-question-by-sharon-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

```
Отгремели давно наши медные трубы, 
Осень жёлтая шлёт письма с той стороны, 
Где друг друга ещё мы немножечко любим, 
Но вчерашние сны никому не нужны. 
Мы друг другу никто, и от этого легче, 
Не болит, не щемит, не срывает мосты. 
У меня свой рассвет, ты встречаешь свой вечер, 
И сейчас мы стоим у последней черты. 

Припев: 
Я не буду, я не буду целовать ХОЛОДНЫХ РУК, 
В этой осени никто не виноват, не виноват. 
Я уехал, я уехал в Петербург, 
А приехал в Ленинград.
```

Послушаем песню: https://yandex.ru/video/preview/4094777836145006418

Петербург - Ленинград. **Музыка – К. Брейтбург Слова – Е. Муравьёв.** 2004 год.

Об одной песне. Олег Баринов. Не так давно впервые после долгого перерыва я услышал песню Гурченко и Моисеева Петербург-Ленинград. И вспомнил, что меня в этой песне всегда мучал один вопрос. В песне есть строчка:
"Ты уехал, ты уехал в Петербург, А приехал в Ленинград".
**Дело в том, что город назывался Петербургом до 1914, а Ленинградом стал в 1924 году.** С 1914 по 1924 год он назывался Петроград. То есть герой песни уехал в 1914 году в Петербург, а приехал в 1924 году в Ленинград. Где он пропадал 10 лет?

[**КРИТИКА**](https://dzen.ru/a/X_B9tNGpBkHKX51e)

Хочу обратить внимание на три наши российские песни, в которых современные поэты-песенники допустили **ужасные ошибки**...  Одна из песен "Петербург-Ленинград" в исполнении Людмилы Гурченко и Бориса Моисеева.

Так вот я не могу понять, как это можно в русском языке написать слова - "...**Я не буду целовать холодных рук..."**. Это абсолютно безграмотно **с точки зрения падежей.** Правильно ведь и писать и говорить "я не буду целовать **холодные руки"**. Или, если оставить в первоначальном варианте, то надо вставить обязательно дополнительное определяющее слово. Например, "Я не буду целовать пальцы холодных рук", или "Я не буду целовать кисти холодных рук" и т.д.

**Вариантов можно добавить разных.** Вот тогда это будет правильным и не бросаться в глаза. Однако и это произведение наша публика также **"проглотила и не подавилась".**

**ВОПРОС**

**Так что же делать с песней?** Надо исправлять, а как?  Я хотела использовать безличное предложение, но в его правильности тоже не очень уверена.

Предложите, пожалуйста, **ваши варианты.** Если припев совсем не нравится и вы хотели бы выразиться поизящнее, то "от целования рук" можно отказаться и заменить строку целиком, но рифма должна быть **точной.**

**Творческая задача!** Если будет хотя бы два ответа, вопрос можно сделать конкурсным.

Ну и конечно, остается вопрос о **правильности** падежей. Почему  в песне возможен **только В.п.?** Критик так и не сказал, в чем здесь **ужасная безграмотность**. На выбор падежа влияют многие факторы (отрицание, партитивность, одушевленность, лексика, стилистика).

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150539/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ну и конечно, остается вопрос о правильности падежей. Почему 
в песне возможен только В.п.? Критик так и не сказал, в чем 
здесь ужасная безграмотность. На выбор падежа влияют многие 
факторы (отрицание, партитивность, одушевленность, лексика, 
стилистика).
```

**МОЙ ОТВЕТ**

Я считаю, что все варианты **с Р.п. неверны,** а именно:

**Мои** предложенные варианты:

(1) Мне уже не видеть вас, **не целовать ваших рук.** Это правильно?

(2) Я не увижу вас, **не буду целовать ваших рук.** Грамматическая ошибка?

Вариант **в песне:** *Я не буду, **я не буду целовать ХОЛОДНЫХ РУК,** В этой осени никто не виноват, не виноват.*

**Пояснение**

1. Сначала в центре внимания был **отрицательный** характер предложения

   Это **«Русская грамматика-80»:** Единая старая норма
   обязательного родительного падежа при глаголах с отрицанием в
   современном языке под влиянием разговорной речи не
   выдерживается: во многих случаях **употребление винительного
   падежа** не только предпочитается, но и является единственно
   правильным.
2. Но потом я предложила ориентацию на другой фактор — **на категорию одушевленности/неодушевленности.**

@user190920 Это нужно самим решать. Мне предложение на слух кажется **некорректным,** автору статьи тоже, причем он видит что-то **совершено недопустимое**. А что? На отрицание он не обращает внимания, ему другое не нравится. **В чем нарушение, куда незаконно залез Р. п.?** Это может быть партитивность или одушевленность. **Скорее последнее.**

Целовать ребенка (одуш.) и целовать крест. **Руки неодушевленные, а их изобразили одушевленными**. Как думаете? //

**А отрицание** здесь может не учитываться, так как ***НЕ*** в нашем случае при **вспомогательном глаголе** (не буду).

3. В моем варианте с **инфинитивным** предложением фактор **одушевленности** сохраняет свое действие, поэтому неверен и этот вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Попробую так:

> Московские послы отговорили также не целовать креста боярам и
> порубежным людям. Соловьев.

Мне уже не целовать руки девушки. / Мне уже не целовать девичьих рук.

1 - руки относятся к девушке, 2 - руки не относятся к конкретной девушке, а вообще говорится о всех девушках и всех руках, руки > девушки > девушка.

> ...я не видел глаз чернее — не желтее, как на испанских портретах, а именно чернее, — это глаза-зрачки, трагические и самоосужденные. Анненский.

То есть не ...ть рук, не ...ть глаз = у него нет знакомых рук или глаз.

Ну и это странно, говорить такое девушке с руками. Получается либо руки не те, либо губ нет), но чего-то нет, отсюда и невозможность выполнить действие. Объектная запись - нет объекта, действие невозможно.

Во фразе:

*Мне уже вАс не видеть, вАших рук не лобзать.*

Акценты совсем другие, поэтому так можно.

Еще есть момент с употреблением множественно и единственного числа, в единственном иначе:

Тебе(мне) не видать её руку. - то есть не видеть руку как объект, не взаимодействовать.

Тебе не видать её руки. - не взять в жёны, падеж меняет семантику, в одном случае речь о руке и действии, в другом о переносном значении рука - женитьба.

Я не буду брать её рукИ. - отказ жениться, Р.П. даёт отрицание понятия.

Я не буду брать её руку. - чепуха, на базаре не буду покупать руку, ногу.

Я не буду брать её рУки. - на базаре, указание, что не будут брать её руки, но возьму другие, то есть желание брать руки у не пропало.

Я не буду брать её рук. - вообще что-то непонятное. Но что-то про никогда больше и впредь, но толи про руки на базаре вообще не буду брать, ни эти ни другие, либо что-то еще, непонятное, но тоже связанное с отрицанием понятия "её руки", желание руки брать пропало, не возьму рук.

То есть ещё занудства, чтобы уже совсем прояснить. Рука-руки - это слово, но у него могут быть разные применимости. Это может быть указание, на что-то конкретное, на объект, а может быть связано с понятием "женитьба", употребления падежа меняет стилистику с объективности, где руки - это объекты, на метафоричность - где взять за руку это часть целостного образ, чего-то большего, связанного с человеком, женитьбой, а не только взаимодействие с объектом. То есть, есть слово-термин - для манипуляции и указания манипуляций с видимыми объектами, отдельными частями; а есть условность связанное с понятием и образом чего-то ещё - часть части, часть целого. Выбор падежа зависит от того, в какую систему нужно попасть - действительную или условную.

Comment: Я уже вас не увижу,  не буду лобзать ваших РУК. Так нельзя? Нужно: Я уже вас не увижу,  не буду лобзать ваши РУКИ.  Почему? Что изменилось?  Почему Р.п. нельзя, а нужен В.п.?

Comment: Родительный падеж намекает, что что-то по какой-то причине не существует, не родилось еще, и рождается от действия. А винительный указывает на конкретную вещь, видимое, и отрицает какое-то условное действие связанное с ней, не разрушая саму вещь. То есть тут получается, у вас рук нет и не будет. И не будет не будет) Потому я их не целую и не буду целовать никогда и никто другой тоже не будет)

Comment: А это почему правильно: Мне уже вАс не видеть, вАших рук не лобзать.  Я вижу только другую грамматику.

Comment: Ваших не лобзать, но другие буду лобзать, тут акцент на ваши, отношения с вами, а не действия с руками. Ваших относится не к рукам, а к глаголу, предикация глагола. Чьих рук - ваших, а не целовать ваших руки - прилагательное, рук каких - ваших.

Comment: Не, в одном случае безличное предложение, а в другом личное, вот и вся разница. А падежи другие.

Comment: В каком и почему?) а как же мня?

Comment: Мне не лобзать ваших рук (Р.п.) – безличное инфинитивное, Я не буду лобзать ваши руки (В.п.)  – личное, двусоставное.

Comment: Ну то есть, мне холодно - это я подвергаюсь воздействию холода. А мне не целовать - я не буду целовать. Есть же разница? Во втором случае явно кому действие принадлежит, несмотря на инфинитив. Если инфинитив, то будет хватить меня целовать - уже не мне, а меня.

Comment: Есть разница, но почему прямое дополнение "руки" в разных падежах?

Comment: Где в разных? в обоих случаях неверно.

Comment: Кошмар, ничего не понимаю) Запишите, пжста, ответ на вопрос по двум моим вариантам без изменения текста. Коротко!  (1) Это правильно? (2) Грамматическая ошибка?

Comment: 1. Мне кажется, оба случая неверны. 2. Какая ошибка не знаю, но так не говорят, когда речь идет о человеке, о каких-то вещах отдельных могут сказать, а о частях людей не говорят. - но я могу ошибаться, я руководствуюсь ссылками НКРЯ https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkUqGAoICAMQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCIgogCh4KA3JlcRIXChXQvdC1INGG0LXQu9C%2B0LLQsNGC0YwwAQ==

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Подождем другие ответы. Иди других ответов?))

Comment: @Sharon я еще добавил, тут вроде не должно быть разногласий.

Comment: Спасибо. но я все же плохо вас понимаю. Мы вот позже послушаем песню, известные актеры исполняют,  Вы тогда на них напишите критику)  Что это они нам тут поют!  С ошибками!  Ну и новую редакцию песни можно предложить. Хороший получится вопрос, творческий. Можно по конкурсу пустить.

Comment: Давайте послушаем, я типа умею песни слушать, меня научили в КСП.

Comment: Завтра, ага? Может, еще будут ответы.

Comment: А КСП - это что?

Comment: Клуб самодеятельной песни, авторской типа, стихи под музыку.

Comment: Так вы песни умеете сочинять, а я и не знала. Тогда вам точно придется предложить свою редакцию. А мы посмотрим, какой такой КСП)